# Should we merge launch-site and launchpad tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[launch-site](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launch-site) tag's description:

> Questions on launch complexes, spaceports or other locales for the
>   launch of spacecraft.

[launchpad](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launchpad) tag's description:

> Questions regarding structures used to aid in the launch of space
>   vehicles.

Should these be merged as synonyms, the second as a synonym of the first?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, those descriptions as they stand now do suggest it's one and the same thing, and that should be corrected. They're not really the same though, launch pad is but one of the many launch site facilities. So I'm inclined to think that both tags should stay, they're not even synonymous in the sense of this site's use, but the [launchpad](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launchpad) tag does need a better description to make it stand out.

---

I edited the [launchpad](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launchpad) tag to now  read:

> Questions regarding vertical rocket launch platforms and facilities in
>   their immediate vicinity supporting final preparations for a rocket
>   launch.

It could still use a clearer description, this is just a fast attempt at making it distinct from [launch-site](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launch-site).